# JMeter Tuning: IF Controller evaluation taking time in seconds

Tags: performance, jmeter, rhino

In my JMeter test plan, I'm storing the value of a variable in a string and checking it for a specific value inside the IF controller block. After introducing this condition, JMeter throughput dropped from 500 req/sec to just 80 req/sec.

The target application was not having any issues but it was JMeter which was spending too much time in evaluating the IF controller block. Has anyone faced this issue? I resolved it by wrapping the code in a sampler and writing the if condition there before proceeding with the request. While this workaround satisfies my requirement, I am not sure how I will resolve a situation if I have to add Jmeter child elements inside the IF controller based on this condition.

Please find below CPU profiling done on JVisualVM.

IF controller configuration: "${mystring}" == "myvalue"

[image]

Comment: this is an interesting problem, and it shows that Rhino JS engine slows everything down. Could be specific to environment or some bottleneck you managed to induce on Rhino. Is it slow for 1 user as well, or only under load? how many threads do you have? (I tried with 400 threads and max I get on If controller is 175 ms; average and median are at 8 ms)

Comment: I am using 150 threads. Before introducing the IF controller block, it was generating the requests at 500 req/sec. After that, it dropped down to 80/sec. I am not observing this for a single thread. I'm using JMeter 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Use [jexl3](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) instead of JavaScript , it is [encourage](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#developing_scripts) by JMeter, in you case `${__jexl3("${mystring}" == "myvalue")}`

If you want/need JavaScript use latest 3.2 [version](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) it improve JavaScript performance.

> JMeter now uses Oracle Nashorn Javascript engine instead of Rhino. This provides a faster execution of Javascript.